# Website with node - couple of questions about browserify or webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, web

I need your help with website project I'm working on. My project consits of 7 html documents, 3 stylesheets, 8 .js (including jquery.min.js and some jquery plugins) and some pictures. I want to bundle and minify it as much as it is possible (it would be good to get only 1 css and 1 js file or maybe 1 js, which contains styles inside).

For clarity - now, when I have all dependencies in html - everything is working properly. But I'm not sure how to set all module.exports and requires. Could you tell me how to do it step-by-step in a proper way?

Many thanks in advance.

PS. I write in ES5, so I don't use Babel.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to make your codebase a bit more tidy.

- Manually group the content of your relevant js files into one and export it as a nodejs module by using `module.exports = module_name` on the top of your merged js script (Repeat as needed for any jscripts in your project).
- Then include the exported module in your main node file and include its main functionality using `var modulesfile = require(./module_name);` Please note directory paths while importing your js modules.
- You can also run a minifier like minifyjs to make your js files size even smaller if they need to be called multiple times from a url. Nodejs installation and usage for minifyjs can be found [here](https://github.com/clarkf/minifyjs).
- You can also call other css from within existing ones by using the

`@import url("./css/filename.css");` Just verify proper css directory paths first.

---

In case you also want to use browserify for node there is a [full guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-css) in the npm website.

Another good and simple solution is to move all of your codebase in a visual studio web project. From there you can do pretty much what you want, organize your scripts and css files (/Scripts and /Content directories) in bundled configuration files etc.

NOTE: All your code has to be migrated to an asp .NET project to use [this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) (as per Microsoft doc) properly.